# Variable coefficient Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Can anyone help with the following differential equation. The errors i am getting are also given.

```
DSolve[{x y''[x] -  h*x  y'[x] + y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, 
  y[1] == 1}, y[x], x]
```

> During evaluation of In[20]:= Solve::incnst: Inconsistent or redundant transcendental equation. After reduction, the bad equation is `-C[1] == 0.` >>
>
> During evaluation of In[20]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[20]:= DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution. >>

```
Out[20]= {}
```

Comment: What is `h`, a function of `x` or a constant, if so is it real, positive or...? The equation is `x y''[x] - h*x y'[x] + y'[x] == 0` or `x y''[x] - h*x y'[x] + y[x] == 0`?

Comment: All too often, DSolve fails due to boundary conditions.  This is the case here.

Comment: h is a real positive constant

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

`y[0] == 0` is at fault here.  Omit it to obtain

```
DSolve[{x y''[x] - h*x y'[x] + y'[x] == 0, y[1] == 1}, y[x], x][[1, 1]]
(* y[x] -> 1 - C[1] ExpIntegralEi[h] + C[1] ExpIntegralEi[h x] *)
```

However, `ExpIntegralEi[h x]` evaluates to Infinity at `x = 0`. Thus, `y[0] == 0` has no solution.

```
y[x] /. % /. x -> 0
(* 1 + C[1] (-∞) - C[1] ExpIntegralEi[h] *)
```